# Take specific columns from excel into Dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I only need 2 columns from an excel sheet, one is always located at B and the other shifts around a bit depending on the month. The one at B doesn't have a name but the other one does, so I was wondering how do I either set a name for the one at B or how do I find the one I know the string of and extract them into a Data-frame?
Current Implementation:

```
file_location = Desktop\Excelfile.xlsx'  
df = pd.read_excel(file_location, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'],usecols="B,K")
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the first unnamed cell is called Unnamed: 1 and the next Unnamed: 2 etc. so I just renamed like this:

```
df = df.rename(columns = {"Unnamed: 1":"Product"})
df = pd.DataFrame(df,columns=["Amount","Product"])
```

and now it works like intended

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

file_location = Desktop\Excelfile.xlsx'  
df = pd.read_excel(file_location)
df = df.rename(columns = {"Unnamed: 1":"Product"})
df = pd.DataFrame(df,columns=["Amount","Product"])
```